# Git merge from a different branch reverts code

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have added an image that describes the flow of our git commits. Basically, two users checkout a develop branch. Then they create their own feature branches and make changes to one file (different parts of the file, so no conflicts). First user changes the file and merges to the develop branch early. Later second user who has been working on the earlier copy of the file, makes their new changes, merges to develop as well. Merge from the second user merges without conflict but reverts changes made by the first user. How do we prevent this? Sometimes minor details are missed when reviewing pull requests that do not have any merge conflicts.

[image]

Comment: Merge from the second user reverts changes in develop?

Comment: @sergzemsk yes, and no conflicts show up

Comment: *Merge from the second user merges without conflict but reverts changes made by the first user*. In normal Git usage, it doesn't. The second user must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the delayed response. The solution was easier than using rebase. The second user has to simply call `git pull origin development` while staying in their feature branch before merging the pull request. If there are conflicts while pulling, the user has to resolve conflicts and push to their branch. Then the reviewer should review the pull request again and approve.

Answer (score 1):

Please ask second user to pull the changes from develop before merging .

```
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: It is possible only if changes from first user already merged to develop

Comment: @sergzemsk, Yes and the first user is merging before than the second user at 3:30 pm according to scenario.

Comment: rebasing before merge to develop is good solution. However, changes from first user shouldn't fade without conflicts. Does whole strings disappear? Could you use `git blame`

Comment: @sergzemsk just one more question, let's say we are doing this on bitbucket or github, then how would rebase fit in? So the second user pushes their branch, makes a pull request, and if a reviewer accepts, they merge it to develop. The whole process is essentially on bitbucket or github website.

Comment: @sergzemsk yes the diff shows that whatever person A merged, person B's commit reverts it completely.

Comment: @pewpewlasers, second user could pull with rebase changes from develop on bitbucket or github before pushing his branch (changes of first user were already on remote develop but were absent on local develop branch)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a rebase and fix the conflicts that may arise:

```
git rebase origin/BRANCH
```

Then if there is conflict try to fix it first.

This will make sure their changes gets to you first and you can deal with them, before commit / push. It is always best to rebase so changes you made are still in the commit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the below solution:
Two user and two feature branch

1.First user merge changes of featureBranch1 to develop
 2.Second user do changes in featureBranch2, but second user has to do below steps to incorporate changes done by first user into develop branch after merge

> **git rebase develop** (This moves the entire featureBranch2 to begin on the tip of the develop branch, effectively incorporating all of the new commits in develop)